# Published Web app to Azure, how do I browse to it, monitor it?

Tags: azure

I have created my first app for azure. It's has an MVC3 web role which writes some data to table storage.

It also has a worker role that does some work behind the scenes to the same data.

**It all works fine in the emulator.**

I've uploaded it all to Azure as a staging deployment, the hosted service it is reports all roles as "ready". The health for all roles is "healthy", though the worker role appears to crash and goes to "degraded" and then resets itself (I assume this is what is happening).

So what now? I have found a "DNS Name" on my Web Role in the form "http://{guid}.cloudapp.net/"

Clicking on that link just gives me a network access error, http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ can't find it either.

What am I missing? Where can I see diagnostics similar to the emulator? I've set "Enable Diagnostics" to use my Azure storage account in each role. How do I get into the storage to see if it has traced anything? Can this be done through the Management Portal?

I've tried searching through MSDN, but I can't find a page that says "and then you click the DNS name link and your website will launch. I'm sure there is a lovely page like that but I can't find it.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In August 2011, the Windows Azure role templates were updated to work with the ASP.NET Universal Providers. As such, when you create a new project, the session state provider is backed by SQL Express by default. If you don't change this to SQL Azure or Cache (or disable session state), you'll run into issues.

I'm not sure this is exactly the issue you're running into, but it's a common one. See Nate Totten's [blog post](http://ntotten.com/2011/08/03/windows-azure-tools-1-4-released/) for more information about this (Nate calls out this issue a few pages down, under **IMPORTANT NOTE**).

Answer (score 1):

You can access diagnostics data directly from Visual Studio Server Explorer. 
Here you have all necessary information: Browsing Storage Resources with Server Explorer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683677.aspx

Personally I use Azure Diagnostics Manager from Cerebrata http://www.cerebrata.com/products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/ that is easy and has a good dashboard

Comment: thanks Ivan, yeah, I know about VS, unfortunately our network is not letting me access Azure via VS at the moment, so hoping to access this info from Management Portal, if possible. I'll check out your other suggestion!

Comment: VS by default uses https (standard 443) port to connect to Azure Storage, if your network blocks this port you can use standard http port (clearly it's not best practice from security point of view). But for a quick look at diagnostics can be useful.

Comment: If you want to do ad-hoc queries of diagnostics storage you can use Linq Pad: http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2010/01/28/How-To-Query-Azure-Log-Tables-with-LINQPad.aspx

Comment: thanks Ivan, yeah I know that too, I have IT\networks working on it :) - thanks knightpfhor!

Comment: Thanks knightpfhor! Great hint!